# CentOS 6.7 and fnmatch() in PHP

Tags: centos, php, posix

The PHP manual states about the [`fnmatch`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fnmatch.php) function:

> **Warning:** For now, this function is not available on non-POSIX compliant systems except Windows.

I noticed that this function is not available on the CentOS 6.7 . The simple test failed:

```
<?php
if (fnmatch('aaa', 'aaa')) {
    echo 'ok';
} else {
    echo 'not much';
}
// Fatal error: Call to undefined function fnmatch()
```

I read about POSIX on Wikipedia as well as about the [LSB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Standard_Base). As far as I understood there is a [test](http://linuxtesting.org/results/testsuite) that supposedly can detect if a distribution is LSB-compliant but it is a little beyond my humble programmer's skills and besides I don't have full access to the OS in the first place.

So before I go into emulating `fnmatch` in my code I'd like to know - is there some way to "enable it" on an OS level or is it entirely not possible?

Comment: Are you using the CentOS provided version of `php`or your own compiled version?  Your test works fine on my CentOS 6.8 machine with PHP 5.3.3  provided by the `php-cli-5.3.3-48.el6_8.x86_64` CentOS package.

Comment: @StephenHarris It's self-compiled PHP 5.5 version and that could be the reason of the problem, thanks!